# Android - Ipay88 got error Access denied finding property "ro.serialno"

Tags: java, android, kotlin, payment-gateway, payment

hello i tried to implement IPayPayment on Android,

```
val checkoutIntent = Ipay.getInstance().checkout(payment,applicationContext, ResultDelegate())
checkoutIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
startActivity(checkoutIntent)
```

but i got error

```
libc: Access denied finding property "ro.serialno"
```

any solution?

Answer (score 4):

The error is thrown later or on Android 9 devices. when we try to access Serial number of device, without application having READ_PHONE_STATE permission.

The error is thrown when serial number is read using reflection.

Apps needing the Build.serial identifier must now request the READ_PHONE_STATE permission and then use the new Build.getSerial() method added in Android 9.

[Migrating Apps to Android 9](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-migration)

Comment: hmm i've added permission for READ_PHONE_STATE, but still same :(

Comment: is the permission granted ?

Comment: yup, but still same
but i already solved, cause the error is deprecated read deviceId, Android O cant getDeviceId, so i change to getImei

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it turned out to be a typo un the final url. I recommend checking all addresses for typos and getting the logcat to print the actual address your app is trying to reach.