# What is accessing serial number - Access denied finding property "ro.serialno"

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an Android app that pulls in a few libraries (Gson, kotlin-reflect, gms, okhttp3, sqlcipher and others).

When I start my app in the debug log and logcat I see this:

> Access denied finding property "ro.serialno"

I tried breaking on all exceptions to catch it but it seems that there is no catchable exception thrown and neither does the error provide a stack trace.

How can I find out what in the libraries code is trying to read this?

Comment: This thread may be a clue for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60277516/android-ipay88-got-error-access-denied-finding-property-ro-serialno

Comment: @ocos in that thread the user knows which lib is causing it. Whereas I am at a loss how to find the culprit lib

Comment: THere's two ways to do it:  write small apps with a handful of those libraries each and binary search down to the one causing it, or read the source code of each one and search for a reference to ro.serialno.  That's about all you can do.